# Some Vector Space clear ups

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm studying for a functional analysis exit exam and I'm asked to show which of the following are vector subspaces of the vector space $F([0,1]), \mathbb{R})$ of all real valued functions on the interval $[0,1]$.

A) All polynomials with real coeffecients of degree exactly 3

B) All bounded integrable functions on $[0,1]$ with $f(0)=0$.

C) All polynomials with real coefficients of degree no more than 3, including the zero polynomial.

**My approaches and questions**

For A, this is not a vector subspace because the zero polynomial is not included.

For B, this one is tricky for me. Is this the same as $l^p$ space? I'm not sure how to show this is a vector space.

C) This is a vector space.

Comment: The addition of two bounded functions $f$ and $g$ is a bounded function. Moreover, if $f$ and $g$ are integrable then $f+g$ it is also integrable. If $f(0)=g(0)$ then $f(0)+g(0)=0.$ If $f$ satisfies the above conditions then $\lambda f$ satisfies such conditions for any $\lambda \mathbb{R}.$ So?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably B) refers to Lebesgue integrable functions, but it works for any measure $\mu$. Let $f,g \in V$, where $V$ the set of  functions described in B), with bounds $C_f$ and $C_g$ respectively, and let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Then
$$
     \left|\int_{[0,1]} (af(x) + bg(x))dx \right|
\leq |a|\left|\int_{[0,1]} f(x)dx\right| + |b|\left| \int_{[0,1]} g(x)dx \right|
<    \infty,
$$
and $(af + bg)(0)=0$; also $|a|C_f + |b|C_g$ is a bound for $af + bg$, so $af + bg \in V$.